# How to update win/lose/draw based on percentage?

Tags: mysql

I wanna ask.

How to find win/lose/draw player based on win rate percentage like this image ?

```
+----+-----------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| id | battle_id | user_id | status | win_rate_percentage |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| 13 |         7 |     542 | lost   |               18.00 |
| 14 |         7 |   93150 | lost   |               36.00 |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+---------------------+
```

and update status to win/lose/draw, the highest score is the winner.

Draw if win_rate_percentage have the same score.

Comment: shall you add another field like gameid ? something is missing

Comment: @jmvcollaborator i just update the table

Comment: Does the hightest score mean the highest win_rate_percentage ? As an amateur in this (gaming ?) area, I find it difficult to grasp the some of the terms. It would be neat if an intended output was given.

Comment: @blabla_bingo yep, win_rate_percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is query written and tested in workbench. Let's make it more interesting by adding two rows which should be deemed as `draw`.

```
create table game ( id int, battle_id int, user_id int, status varchar(10), win_rate_percentage decimal(5,2));
insert game values
(13,    7,  542,    'lost', 18.00),
(14,    7,  93150,  'lost', 36.00),
(15,    8,  542,    'lost', 20.00),
(14,    8,  93150,  'lost', 20.00)
;
update game tb1, (select t1.battle_id, mx,count(1) ct from
                    game t1, (select battle_id,max(win_rate_percentage) mx 
                             from game 
                             group by battle_id) t2
                 where t1.battle_id=t2.battle_id and t1.win_rate_percentage=t2.mx
                 group by t1.battle_id) tb2
set  tb1.status=case 
                when ( tb1.win_rate_percentage=tb2.mx and tb2.ct>1 ) then 'draw' 
                when ( tb1.win_rate_percentage=tb2.mx and tb2.ct=1 ) then 'win'
                else 'lose' end
where tb1.battle_id=tb2.battle_id 
;

select * from game;

-- result set:
# id, battle_id, user_id, status, win_rate_percentage
13, 7, 542, lose, 18.00
14, 7, 93150, win, 36.00
15, 8, 542, draw, 20.00
14, 8, 93150, draw, 20.00
```